# Como tirar o 0. do 'round' PHP

Tags: php

Como faço para tirar esse *0.* da conta abaixo..

```
$idMark = 6;  
$rating[5] = 4;

$bar5estrelas = ($ratings[5] == 0) ? 0 : round(($ratings[5]/$idMark), 2);

Resultado: 0.67
```

Como o retiro o ***0.* deixando apenas 67** ?

Comment: Isso é algum tipo de fator? Não pode simplesmente multiplicar por 100 e arredondar?

Comment: @utluiz Já ta resolvido!

Comment: Ok, eu vi que você aceitou a resposta e conseguiu o resultado esperado. Porém usar manipulação de strings em cima de valores numéricos me soa como uma bela gambiarra. E se o resultado da divisão for algo como `1.23`?

Comment: @utluiz ai vai meio q ser inutil o str_replace e continuar normal neh..?

Comment: Sim, e isso se chama *inconsistência*.

Comment: @utluiz foi o que eu disse claramente na resposta, como não dá pra ter certeza de qual o objetivo do código não tem como afirmar um melhor caminho, já que pegar o valor após o numero ponto já soa estranho por si só.

Comment: é um sistema de avaliação, por exemplo se tiver 20.000.000 de votos em 5 estrelas e o total de votos em todas as estrelas for 35.000.000 vai dar 0,57 e vai ter esse 0. sempre q preciso retirar para por o value="57" na progress bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se afirmar qual a melhor maneira de fazer pois eu não sei qual será o objetivo, já que o seu código me parece algo com porcentagem mas não consigo ter certeza do que realmente você quer fazer

Entretanto você pode tentar:

```
round(($ratings[5]/$idMark), 2) * 100;
```

Ou você pode tentar converter pra string e tirar o 0. com `str_replace` (acredito que o php já converta para string quando usamos funções com `str_` por exemplo):

```
str_replace('0.', '', round(($ratings[5]/$idMark), 2));
```

*Mas é como eu disse*, não sei se é o melhor caminho, pois não sei qual o objetivo do código.

Se estiver trabalhando com porcentagem (o que não dá pra ter certeza devido a variável `$ratings[5]`) você poderia simplesmente fazer assim:

```
round(($ratings[5] / $idMark) * 100);
```

Comment: Ae usei o str_replace, deu certo :D, muito obrigado